# visual studio 2010 crystal reports wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I created my report but I cant seem to bind the report viewer with the report source? I think they changed the way things are done?

Answer (score 3):

From SAP support site
http://forums.sdn.sap.com/message.jspa?messageID=8995372

```
//Using the ReportDocument SDK
this._report = new ReportDocument();
this._report.Load(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CrystalReportWpfApplication1\CrystalReportWpfApplication1\CrystalReport1.rpt");
this.reportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = this._report;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a very late answer, but might help others who are looking for a similar issue.
If you want to Bind the ReportSource, You need to enclose the the CrystalReportViewer control within a WindowsFormsHost in a UserControl and declare a dependency property of type string. You need to set the ReportSource from here. You cannot directly bind it from XAML with the native control.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but just like the last post I though it might be helpful to others.

The CrystalReportViewer for WPF has a property called "Content". This Content property is literally a StackPanel, with 3 Children, the third being this new element "ViewerCore", which fills all space available on the DockPanel (LastChildFill).

The ReportSource property is in this ViewerCore, so to access this ViewerCore (ReadOnly) property, you need to do the following:

add a reference to SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer

add a using statement `using SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;`

and then to set the source of the report use

`ViewerCore view = crReportViewer.ViewerCore;  view.ReportSource = cryRpt;`

HTH
Noelle