# Using CrystalReport and WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Thanks for read my Question..

I have a Report on Crystal Report, and I am using CrystalReport for VS2010, VS2010, SQl Server 2008 and WPF targeting .Net Framework 4.0.

The question is.. I am allready made a Report and I have and App on WPF in which I need to call, embed or whatever it is take to show the report.

How could I ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to use the CrystalReportViewer control to hold the report, please see [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703949/visual-studio-2010-crystal-reports-wpf) question.